# What is the exact fallout of a compromised LinkedIn OAuth2 client secret?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Let's say I have a LinkedIn app used for OAuth 2.0 authentication. The app has a couple of permissions selected and a list of whitelisted redirect URLs. Let's say that I trust my LinkedIn credentials are secure, having been changed recently. Further, I have no reason to suspect that anyone malicious has gotten their hands on my app's client id or secret.

But now I need to respond to a what-if: What if I assume the client secret has been compromised?

What should my response be to this scenario? What is the worst an attacker could do with the client id and secret, but no access to the allowed redirect URLs?

Making a new app will be painful, because I will have to go through the approval process a second time to get the full profile permission added. And it sounds like this can take weeks to complete. Am I safe continuing with the "compromised" client secret for a few weeks, then deploying an update to use a new app when it is ready?